# Potential and integral (electrodynamics)

Tags: integration, electromagnetism, potential-theory

I'm supposed to find the vector potential $A(x)$

1. the field generated by an infinite conducting wire of section $\pi a^2$, in which flows a constant current density $j=j \cdot \theta(a-r)\hat{z}$ where $r=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}$

I got kinda stuck on the integral so i decided to ask for some assistance here on MSE instead of PSE, thanks for understnading

So since $j_x,j_y$ are both 0 we have $A_x, A_y=0$

Since $\nabla \times B=\nabla \times(\nabla \times A) = \nabla(\nabla \cdot A)-\nabla^2 A=\mu_0J$ and by definition $\nabla \cdot A = 0$ $\rightarrow$ $\nabla^2 A = -\mu_0J$ which is a Poission's eequation with known solution:

$$A(z)=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int\frac{J(r')}{\eta}d\tau'=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int\frac{j\cdot \theta(a-r)\hat{z}}{r}d\tau'=\hat{z} \ \frac{\mu_0j\theta}{4\pi}\int \frac{a-r}{r}d\tau'$$

So here is where i'm a bit unsure.

Can i just use cylindrical coordinates and say:

$$A(r)=\hat{z} \ \frac{\mu_0j\theta}{4\pi}\int \frac{a-r}{r}rdzdrd\psi$$

So can i say $a=\pi r^2$ and substitue in and get:

$$A(r)=\hat{z} \ \frac{\mu_0j\theta}{4\pi}\int \frac{\pi r^2-r}{r}rdzdrd\psi=\hat{z} \ \frac{\mu_0j\theta}{4\pi}\int (\pi r -1)rdzdrd\psi$$

and $r$ is a constant and if i just evaluate the integral:
$$A(r)=\hat{z} \ \frac{\mu_0j\theta 2z(r^2-1)}{2}$$

But this just feels wrong...

Appreciate any help

PS: i realise i'm using different notations through out....hopefully it's still clear..

Comment: Is $theta$ a constant? or is the current density a function of the angle?

Comment: that is unfortunately not mentioned in the problem. I thought about that too, but since they didnt address it i decided to treat it like a constant

Comment: The Heaviside function, also known as the unit step function, is sometimes designated $\theta(x)$.  Here $\theta(a-r)$ equals $0$ for $r>a$ and equals $1$ for $r<a$.

Comment: $\theta$ here is definitely the Heaviside step function, especially in this context.

Comment: @MarkViola I was simply reaffirming that this is what the problem is referring to. My apologies if I have offended you some how.

Comment: @Chris Not at all.  No apology required.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Let $\vec J(\vec r)=\hat z j$ for $\rho <a$ and $\vec J(\vec r)=0$.  Applying the Biot-Savart Law, we find that

$$\begin{align}
\vec B(\vec r)&=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^a \frac{j \hat z \times (\vec \rho-\vec \rho')}{(\rho^2+\rho'^2-2\rho\rho'\cos(\phi-\phi')+(z-z')^2)^{3/2}}\,\rho'\,d\rho'\,d\phi'\,dz'\\\\
&=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^a \frac{j (\hat \phi \rho-\hat \phi' \rho')}{(\rho^2+\rho'^2-2\rho\rho'\cos(\phi-\phi')+(z-z')^2)^{3/2}}\,\rho'\,d\rho'\,d\phi'\,dz'\\\\
&=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^a \frac{2j (\hat \phi \rho-\hat \phi' \rho')}{\rho^2+\rho'^2-2\rho\rho'\cos(\phi-\phi')}\,\rho'\,d\rho'\,d\phi'\\\\
&=\hat \phi \frac{\mu_0 j}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^a \frac{\rho-\cos(\phi') \rho'}{\rho^2+\rho'^2-2\rho\rho'\cos(\phi')}\,\rho'\,d\rho'\,d\phi'\\\\
&=\hat \phi \frac{\mu_0 j}{2\pi} \int_0^{\min(\rho,a)} \frac{2\pi}{\rho}\rho'\,d\rho'\\\\
&=\begin{cases}
\hat \phi \frac{\mu_0 j a^2}{2\rho}&, \rho >a\\\\
\hat \phi \frac{\mu_0 j \rho}{2}&, \rho <a
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

which could have been obtained more efficiently by exploiting symmetry and applying Amperes' Law.